# Заданный массив с 2n чисел. Поменять местами его половины

Tags: c++

Заданный массив с 2n чисел. Поменять местами его половины.

Comment: Вам нужно просто пройти по элементам массива в цикле и обменять функцией std::swap значения i-ого и n-i-ого элементов, если я правильно понял вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
for_each(a, a+N, [](auto &x){swap(x,*(&x+N)); } );
```

Запускаемый пример http://ideone.com/VnIzLC

Answer (score 1):

Если из модели a,b,c,d нужно сделать c,d,a,b, то:

```
double number = 0;
for(int I = 0; I  < n[половина длины массива]; I++)
{
number = mas[I];
mas[I] = mas[I+n];
mas[I+n] = number;
}
```